# ADO.NET and Disposing without Using

Tags: ado.net, dispose

I have a project that isn't using USING anywhere with their ADO.NET code.  I am cleaning up their unclosed connections.  Is the below code a best practice with try/catch/finally.  I also have some that contains SqlTransaction that I'm disposing in between the command and connection dispose.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyNGConnectDashBoardConnectionString"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: You just asked a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525307/does-sqltransaction-need-to-have-dispose-called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no need to worry about closing the connection when using the `SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataset)` method. This method closes the connection after performing every Fill.

Also, there is no need to call `SqlCommand.Dispose()` since the command itself has no unmanaged resources to clean up. What you should be concerned about is if `SqlConnection.Close()` is called at some point. This is done after Fill.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is using `using` instead of try/finally :)

However in your case even using is not needed, because `Fill()` closes the connection:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyNGConnectDashBoardConnectionString"].ToString())
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("your sql is here", con);
        da.Fill(ds);
```

Also simple re-throwing exceptions makes no sense at all. If you need to log error, just use plain `throw;` as @Cory suggested.

Comment: I know but I cant update 200 database calls and test them in the time I have so I have to work with what I have.

Comment: Added more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine. It is always a good idea to dispose of objects that use unmanaged resources. However, if you get sick of always explicitly calling Dispose, the best practice is probably to use the `using`:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyNGConnectDashBoardConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw; // I changed this too!
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you almost always want to simply `throw` if you're going to "rethrow" an exception. You lose some of your stack trace if you `throw ex;`.