# How to check state before disposing SqlTransaction

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have following code that uses SqlTransaction. I have called dispose in catch and finally blocks.. But I have not checked whether it is already disposed before calling Dispose(). How can we check whether the SqlTransaction is already disposed before calling Dispose()?

I have referred [MSDN:SqlTransaction.Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326309%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). But that does not cover my question.

Also referred http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.dispose(v=vs.100).aspx

Note: I already know that `TransactionScope` has advantages over `SqlTransaction`. But I am trying to understand the SqlTransaction’s dispose.

**CODE**

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlTransaction transaction = null;

            try
            {
                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

                sessionID = GetSessionIDForAssociate(connection, empID, transaction);
                //Other code

                //Commit
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                //Rollback
                if (transaction != null)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    transaction.Dispose();
                }

                //Throw exception
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (transaction != null)
                {
                    transaction.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can we check whether the SqlTransaction is already disposed before
>   calling Dispose()?

You don't have to. Calling dispose twice won't cause you any problem.

[Dispose - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx)

> If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object
>   must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw
>   an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times. Instance
>   methods other than Dispose can throw an ObjectDisposedException when
>   resources are already disposed.

But if you want to only call Dispose once then you can either use a boolean flag to set when the transaction is disposed or you can set it to null. Or remove the call to dispose in `catch` block since `finally` block will always be called.

Since SqlTransaction implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), **its better if you use it with using block**. Something like:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            sessionID = GetSessionIDForAssociate(connection, empID, transaction);
            //Other code

            //Commit
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            //Rollback
            if (transaction != null)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }

            //Throw exception
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Since using block acts like `try/finally` block, and it will ensure the disposal of the transaction upon its completion (even if the exception occurs). So you don't have to manually call `Dispose`.

Answer (score 2):

Add `transaction=null` after you call dispose and then your existing tests will work.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to check to see whether it's been disposed already? You can avoid calling `Dispose` twice by simply omitting the call from your `catch` block:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlTransaction transaction = null;

    try
    {
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

        sessionID = GetSessionIDForAssociate(connection, empID, transaction);
        //Other code

        //Commit
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        //Rollback
        if (transaction != null)
        {
            // No need to dispose here - finally is always called
            transaction.Rollback();
        }

        //Throw exception
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (transaction != null)
        {
            // Always called, so no need to dispose elsewhere.
            transaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `.Dispose()` call from catch block. Finally is ALWAYS executed, so this way you are trying two times to dispose transaction.

It does not answer "how can I know if it was already disposed" but probably solve your problem.